# I am having issues styling wordpress contact page

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Please I'm having issues styling the [contact page](http://www.nimechepti.com/contact-us/) . I'll love to change Address, email and phone number colours to white. [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDHb6.png),

[image]

I've tried inspecting element, but can't find the actual file to modify.

Comment: the contact page link is broken.

Comment: remove maintaince mode

Comment: Maintenance Mode Removed. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find the file is because it's in-between `script` tags. Can you not do it using the WYSIWYG controls?

If you want to do it with CSS, put the following in your theme's custom.css or your child themes styles.css (Or if your theme has theme options, it may be in there):

```
.page-template-contact .info-strip .info-block p,
.page-template-contact .info-strip .info-block a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

This will apply it only to those blocks on the contact page. The important also prevents it being overridden by inline CSS added by WYSIWYG editors, so bare this in mind when you want to change it 2 months down the line :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-template-contact .info-strip .info-block p,
.page-template-contact .info-strip .info-block a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Would you please add above code in your [style.css](http://www.nimechepti.com/wp-content/themes/bulldozer/css/style.css) ?